# Yii with Hybridauth error login URL was not found

Tags: php, yii, hybridauth

I am trying to install `hybridauth` on my website.

I followed everything from this [website](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/hybridauth/). In the login page when click on google it goes to the url:

http://www.example.com/hybridauth/default/login/?provider=google

and displays the error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /hybridauth/default/login/ was not found on this server.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your `config/main.php`, under `urlManager`, do you have `'urlFormat' => 'path'` and `'showScriptName'=>false`? What do other URL's look like on your site?

Comment: @Brett Gregson  'urlFormat' => 'path' is there but 'showScriptName'=>false is not there do u want me to add it there

Comment: Yeah try add it let's see

Comment: @Brett Gregson shows the same error "The requested URL /hybridauth/default/login/ was not found on this server."